# Delete tables from table based on table size

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use this table to store messages. I would like to delete rows by date if the size of the table is bigger than 10 MB. Is this possible in Oracle?

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

Comment: Define "size of table" (there are multiple ways to calculate that which will produce different results some of which will not change when you delete data from the table).  Do you want to delete all rows older than some date if the table is too big or do you want to delete enough rows that the table is less than 10 MB?  You could write a procedure that implements whatever logic you want and schedule a background job via `dbms_scheduler` that calls your procedure every night to clean up the table.  I'm not sure that's exactly what you're after.

Comment: By table size I mean the memory size with all the data combined. Maybe there is no such thing like table size in Megabytes?

Comment: "memory size" implies RAM.  But I assume you are talking about on disk storage.  The most common measure of "table size", however, would not change if you deleted all the data from the table.  That seems like it would be problematic in your case (but maybe not, you need to explain your requirements to us).

Comment: Well I want to use Oracle 11g XE. I wan to clean HDD old data because HDD is very limited.

Comment: Deleting data does not reduce the amount of allocated space which is what the Oracle XE 11 GB limit would look at.  You'd free up space in that particular table for future inserts into that particular table but the size of the table would not decrease.